# get privileges on information_schema mysql

Tags: mysql, information-schema

If I open MySQL Administrator and I try to delete one event from the table events of the database information_schema I get this error:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'
```

What privileges do I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The information_schema tables are all read only, there is no way to delete any rows there.

To drop an event, use the `DROP EVENT` statement.