# Is there a way to use the current row's (that is about to be inserted) id number inside query itself?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to use the id for naming the image file inside a row. Is there a way to use the id of the (current) row inside the query itself. (I know about the lastInsertId() but it works generally after the query and not inside it.)

```
INSERT INTO table (id, intro, detail, image) 
VALUES (null, introtext, detailtext, get_the_id_of_this_query_itself.jpg )
```

I know that i could just save the extension of this image (like .jpg) and then afterwards use it together with the id of the article. But i wondered if this is possible.

added afterwards:
Could we perhaps use a subquery inside the insert query that increments max(id) by one and then add .jpg string for the image name ?

Comment: When you say ID, are you referring to the unique ROWID, or the row ID populated from a user-defined sequence?

Comment: yes i mean a unique number with ID. the id will be populated when the query is processed. but i am looking to use it before it is or as it is populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table (id, intro, detail, image)
SELECT id, 'introtext', 'detailtext', CONCAT('id_', id, '.jpg')
FROM (  SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT AS id
        FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES`
        WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` LIKE 'database_name' AND `TABLE_NAME` LIKE 'table') AS h
```

- **[INSERT ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)**
- **[AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)**
- **[get privileges for information_schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588002/get-privileges-on-information-schema-mysql)**
- **[from clause subqueries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/from-clause-subqueries.html)**

Replace `table` and `database_name` accordingly.

Comment: I get a "0 rows inserted. (Query took 0.0543 sec)" when i try this query. somehow it doesn't insert anything.

Comment: You need to replace `table` both in `INSERT INTO` aswell as in `TABLE_NAME LIKE 'table'`. Remove the `INSERT` line and see if data is fetched.

Comment: Try entering `database_name` aswell to current database. `DATABASE()` might not work.

Comment: great! as you said i forgot the second "table" to change. now it works. and it took just 0.0008 sec! that is it. Thank you very much @RobinCastlin

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to know what the ID will be before insertion.  It's also not recommended to use this data as a real value.  This column is supposed to be a transparent identifier of the row.  This is useful for `JOIN`s.  The fact that it can be convenient for lookups is incidental and should not be relied upon.

This ID should be treated as if it could change at any time.  If you need another identifier such as an ordinal number, it should be stored in a separate field and handled by the application.

Imagine if this script is being accessed at high speed.  Many of these `INSERT` queries may be running simultaneously (and even on different servers) so the ID cannot be known until the query completes.  Even after the query completes, the ID may be changed after replication syncs and the `image` column's data may be inconsistent.

Comment: yes you are completely right about this. but this table is not used that often. thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Even though technically you can achieve this in MySQL with a separate table for sequencing and a `BEFORE` trigger

Table schemas:

```
CREATE TABLE articles_seq 
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE articles
(
  `id` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT 0, 
  `intro` VARCHAR(128), 
  `detail` VARCHAR(128), 
  `image` VARCHAR(128)
);
```

The trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_bi_articles
BEFORE INSERT ON articles
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO articles_seq () VALUES ();
  SET NEW.id = LAST_INSERT_ID(), 
      NEW.image = CONCAT(NEW.id, '.jpg');
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Now you can insert records like this

```
INSERT INTO articles (`intro`, `detail`, `image`) VALUES 
('Intro text 1', 'Details text 1', '.jpg'),
('Intro text 2', 'Details text 2', '.png');
```

Outcome:

```
| ID |        INTRO |         DETAIL | IMAGE |
|----|--------------|----------------|-------|
|  1 | Intro text 1 | Details text 1 | 1.jpg |
|  2 | Intro text 2 | Details text 2 | 2.jpg |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b74f6/1)** demo

**you better off without it**. You can use a view instead

```
CREATE TABLE articles
(
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  `intro` VARCHAR(128), 
  `detail` VARCHAR(128), 
  `ext` VARCHAR(32)
);

CREATE VIEW vw_articles AS
SELECT id, intro, detail, CONCAT(id, '.', ext) image
  FROM articles;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/350e4e/2)** demo

Comment: wow thank you for that extreme answer. this is a great way but in my case the table is used commonly for general purpose and there are inserted other rows that don't use the image table as well. thank you really much for this answer.